# Prevent AWS CodeDeploy from adding a lifecycle hook to an Auto-scaling group when creating a deployment group?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-code-deploy

Recent functionality added to AWS CodeDeploy causes it to add a lifecycle hook to an Auto-scaling group whenever that Auto-scaling group has been targeted by a new deployment group. The lifecycle hook causes a deployment to be triggered whenever a new instance is spun up by the ASG. I *don't* want this lifecycle hook to be created, but there doesn't seem to be any way that I can see to prevent it from being created automatically. I can always go in and delete the lifecycle hook after the fact, but it would be great if I could just prevent it from being created in the first place. How can I preempt the lifecycle hook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are not interested in the ASG lifecycle events, change your codedeploy's deployment group configuration just EC2 instance tags to which you want to deploy instead of specifying an ASG.

This should solve your problem, but not recommended.

Comment: @jcgrowley please mark as answered if this solved your issue.

Comment: How do you configure a deployment group to target an ELB? In the console, it looks like the only options are "Amazon EC2", "Auto Scaling group", and "On-premises instance".

Comment: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/integrations-aws-elastic-load-balancing.html

Comment: This documentation explains how to reroute traffic from one ELB to another during a blue/green deployment, and how to deregister instances from an ELB during a deployment, but it doesn't actually explain how to configure a deployment group that targets only instances behind an ELB (as opposed to an ASG or EC2 instances with given tags.)

Comment: So you want to configure an ASG in the CodeDeploy configuration, but you do not want CodeDeploy to act on the ASG events? That sounds conflicting. I think I misinterpreted the recent announcement from AWS, which says ELB is supported in CodeDeploy implicitly. I've updated my answer and removed ELB. You probably will need to include EC2 tags in the CodeDeploy config.

Comment: Right -- targeting an ASG is a convenient way to target all relevant instances when performing subsequent deployments -- that is to say, not the initial deployment of the code when the instance first starts up. I have user data scripts that do that. Ultimately it probably would be a good idea to divorce code deployment from user data, but right now I'm just focusing on using CodeDeploy for follow-up deployments. Using EC2 tags should work fine. Thanks for your input!

Comment: @jcgrowley were you ever able to get CodeDeploy to deploy to any instances in the ASG without having the LifeCycle hook get added? Or what solution did you ultimately end up going with? I understand your use case and am trying to resolve a similar situation.